# speeding up dynamic web page generation in python django

Tags: python, django

I am learning django now and I am learning to but a price comparison web app utilizing Amazon advertising API. My overall work flow is as below:

1. user submit a keyword for query
2. the keyword is being searched in Amazon for listing some items, currently 10
3. each item was assigned an unique number by Amazon, which the number is submitted to Amazon again for extracting additional information about the item such as a thumbnail, price. This will be done by a for-loop.
4. Information from the first and second query to Amazon will be listed on the web page and returned to the user.

The flow is now working, but I found the webapp to be quite slow in the django development server: I search for a book and it takes Amazon more than 10 seconds to extract information for the first 10 item searched, and display all the pictures all at once.

I am aware of the requirement from Amazon that we cannot make more than 1 request per second, but in view of other price comparison website working much faster, I am wondering if there is any programmatic mean for optimizing it.

I have thought of several ways:

1. caching product information
2. speeding up the for-loop in step 3
3. display the text in the page to user first, and load the picture later.

Method 1 is doable, I am not sure if method 2 or 3 is feasible.

Can anyone give any hints?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you're all doing this synchronously in a single view? If so, try breaking things up into several views that you call asynchronously using ajax requests. That way you can start displaying things one by one as soon as they come back.

Comment: @Jaap3 what do you mean by single view? something related to celery?

Comment: With a view I mean a function that takes a http request and returns a http response: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/

Comment: @Jaap3 yes, I do step 2,3 in one function, can you show me an example? Thanks!